# Typescript babel-plugin-module-resolver

Tags: typescript, react-native, babeljs

Hello is there an equivalent of babel-plugin-module-resolver for typescript.
I am trying to resolve "react-native" to "react-native-web". Example below.

```
import { View } from "react-native" 
// should resolve to to once compiled or run using ts-node or ts-loader
import { view } from "react-native-web"
```

I have tried solving the issue for a while before asking the question with no success. Here's what I've tried.

first attempt: - unsuccessful

```
// tsconfig.json
"baseUrl": "./" 
"paths": {
  "react-native": ["node_modules/react-native-web"]
},
"skipLibCheck": true
```

second attempt: using Babel as a translator: successful but not ideal or elegant. Issues when using vscode debug due to an issue when pass .tsx, .ts extensions to the babel-node even with the --extensions ".ts,tsx" flag.

```
// .babelrc
{
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ],
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
}
```

does anyone have any ideas? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't rewrite your import paths: see [this declined suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15479).  You'll have to use Babel or one of the other third-party tools from that thread.  If you give specific steps to reproduce the problem you had with debugging, I may be able to help with that.

Comment: Thanks for the offer Matt, I've gone back to using babel with @babel/preset-typescript and the babel resolver so its all working. I was hoping for a way for ts to resolve like the babel-plugin-module-resolver so I could use ts-node over babel-node.

Comment: Use babel-plugin-module-resolver with tsconfig.json `"compilerOptions.baseUrl": "."`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths

> Typescript by default mimics the Node.js runtime resolution strategy of modules. But it also allows the use of path mapping which allows arbitrary module paths (that doesn't start with "/" or ".") to be specified and mapped to physical paths in the filesystem. The typescript compiler can resolve these paths from tsconfig so it will compile OK. But if you then try to execute the compiled files with node (or ts-node), it will only look in the node_modules folders all the way up to the root of the filesystem and thus will not find the modules specified by paths in tsconfig.